# Adobe AIR in iOS8 - notification action in backgorund

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, ios8

I've been running some tests here and I just want to confirm if someone could do something with this issue.

When I execute a notification action in background using new iOS8 notifications, the app starts in background and runs the delegate handleActionWithIdentifier after iOS initialization (I see how didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is called before).

But the AS3 is not called so I cannot handle any action in that end.

Anyone with the same problem? possible solutions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally I realized that I cannot reach AS3 execution if I use a mxml file for the AS3 app. But using AS3 files, I can reach the execution at least for the first main sprite initialization, so I can handle the notification response at that moment.

Comment: I've been waiting for the applicationComplete event, but it never comes, probably there are some other methods you can listen before the app get killed.